# How to call all of the methods of a class in a method of another class in java

Tags: java, javafx

I am designing a JavaFX application and I need to call the Application class of one of the windows in the Controller of another window.

**MainController.java:**

```
public class MainController {

  @FXML
  public Button buttonLogin;

  @FXML
  public Button buttonNeuAnmelden;

  @FXML
  public void handleButtonLoginAction(ActionEvent event) {
    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    System.out.println("LoginButton geclickt!");

  }

  @FXML
  public void handleButtonNeuAnmeldenAction(ActionEvent event) {
    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    System.out.println("NeuAnmeldenButton Geclickt!");

  }

}
```

**LoginApp.java:**

```
public class LoginApp extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("/design/Login.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

I specifically need to run all of the methods of `LoginApp`, meaning `main(String[] args)` and `start(Stage primaryStage)` class in `handleButtonLoginAction()` method as if the whole class as it is has been called exactly at that point.

How do I do this?

Comment: *"as if the whole class had been called"* What does this mean? You don't "call classes", you call methods. Also, your `main(...)` method calls `launch()` which [can only be called once](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) in the lifetime of the application.

Comment: But you're still implying a class is in some way executable: "What that class does". A class doesn't do anything: the methods in the class do something. What are you actually trying to do? Even if you make the language make sense here, semantically this doesn't make any sense at all. The `Application` class represents the whole application and its lifecycle. You should have only one `Application` instance in any JVM, and its `start()` method will be invoked for you when you launch the application. It really doesn't make sense to start the application from within the application.

Comment: That's why I said it like that! Since I know you can't call classes. But I need exactly what that class does at that point in the event handler...

Comment: I want to switch to my LoginApp when LoginButton is clicked and I don't want to creat the stages in my Controller so I thought maybe I can use my already working LoginApp which has everything I need...

Comment: You just want to access the existing window from `MainController` and display the contents of `Login.fxml` in it?

Comment: I specifically want to call the `Stage` that I have defined in `LoginApp` in the event handler of `MainController`

Comment: (Again with calling classes: I assume you mean "show the `Stage`".) So you need to encapsulate the login (content and window) in another object. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to refactor this quite a bit. Define a `LoginView` class that is independent of your `Application` subclass:

```
public class LoginView {

    private final Stage displayStage ;

    private final Scene scene ;

    public LoginView(Stage displayStage) throws IOException {
        this.displayStage = displayStage ;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("/design/Login.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();        
        scene = new Scene(root);
        displayStage.setScene(scene);
        displayStage.setTitle("Benutzerverwaltung");
    }

    public LoginView() throws IOException {
        this(new Stage());
    }

    public void show() {
        displayStage.show();
    }

    public void hide() {
        displayStage.hide();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then your `Application` class looks like:

```
public class LoginApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        LoginView loginView = new LoginView(primaryStage);
        // ...
        loginView.show();
    }
}
```

Your question didn't show how `MainController` is related to the application, but all you need to do is pass a reference to the `loginView` you created to the `MainController`, and then call `loginView.show()` from the method in the `MainController`.

Comment: Yup! Seperating the App into App and View and adding show methods and using them in other classes, was the answer... Thanks!